# How to render usercontrols in asp:panel horizontally? 

Tags: asp.net, html, layout, user-controls, panel

I have many usercontrols added to a asp:panel, but the controls render vertically with each new one  below the previous one. How can I render the controls horizontally (with scrollbar if the controls' width exceeds the screen width)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET `Panel` control usually renders to `<div>` element at client-side. You should add a class to it:

```
<asp:Panel CssClass='float-left'>
```

Then in CSS float them:

```
.float-left
{
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add each user control in table's cell horizontally or set/apply CSS `display:inline` attribute to the container of user-control.

Answer (score 0):

as html parser  renders user controls as an entire html element you should create a table with desired columns and rows and put your user controls inside td tags.
if the count of your user controls are unknown and is decided by code at runtime, you should create an asp:table and add pre-defined table cells and rows.

hope that helps.
regards.

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <UC:Special_Ad_Holder_UC ID="Special_ad_holder_UC1" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <UC:Special_Ad_Holder_UC ID="Special_ad_holder_UC2" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <UC:Special_Ad_Holder_UC ID="Special_ad_holder_UC3" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <UC:Special_Ad_Holder_UC ID="Special_ad_holder_UC4" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <UC:Special_Ad_Holder_UC ID="Special_ad_holder_UC5" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <UC:Special_Ad_Holder_UC ID="Special_ad_holder_UC6" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <UC:Special_Ad_Holder_UC ID="Special_ad_holder_UC7" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <UC:Special_Ad_Holder_UC ID="Special_ad_holder_UC8" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <UC:Special_Ad_Holder_UC ID="Special_ad_holder_UC9" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```